# MongoDB query nested array knowing parent id element (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

If I have a MongoDB collection that looks like this:

```
_id: ObjectId(" <a objectid> ")
id: " <a userid> "
__v: 0
subscribedTo: Object
```

With or without Mongoose, how can I query the first child of object `subscribedTo`, which is called `infl` and it's an array?

what I'm trying is this, but it says "infl" is undefined:

```
const foundUser = await Sub.findOne ({ "id" : userId });
console.log("this "+JSON.stringify(foundUser.subscribedTo.infl))
```

Although when I console log only `foundUser.subscribedTo` it correctly logs:

```
this [{"infl":["item1","item2"],"inflId":["item1id","item2id"]}]
```

Comment: What is `.subscribedTo.infl` ? What do you get if you only console log `foundUser` ?

Comment: infl is an array, first child of subscribedTo which is an object. If i console log JSON.stringify(foundUser) i get the whole json i shown at the top: this {"_id":" xxx","id":" xxx ","__v":0,"subscribedTo":[{"infl":["item1","item2"],"inflId":["item1id","item2id"]}],"updatedAt":"2020-12-13T14:39:53.018Z"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code output, `subscribedTo` is not an `object`,

it's an array of objects.
So, what you need is :

```
subscribedTo[0].infl
```

This will solve your issue for this case.